# How do I move on from this room in 1000 Amps?

Tags: 1000-amps

I haven't been playing for very long, and am already stuck.  This seems like a bad sign.

[image: 1000 Amps level]

I can jump to the sides and touch the nodes, but instantly fall through the floor and lose my progress.  Without the charge I don't have enough height on my jump to get through the ceiling.

What am I missing?  Is there some logical way to do this?   Or does it just require more dexterity for the "Jump and back again" than I possess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Touch the filled in blocks (energy blocks) on each side, then you get enough jump height to get out of the room.

Jump left, touch both energy blocks, and get back to the middle "platform", jump right, touch both energy blocks. Done.

Comment: Translation: More dexterity required.  Right.