# How do I teleport in 1000 Amps?

Tags: 1000-amps

I started playing 1000 Amps knowing next to nothing about the game.  While reading up about it (trying to solve [my other question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/52659/how-do-i-move-on-from-this-room-in-1000-amps)), I discovered that Plug apparently has a Teleport ability, that is activated by clicking.

But I've been clicking around randomly, and nothing seems to have happened.  Does this unlock partway through?  Or is there some special trick to it I'm misunderstanding?  How does it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Early in the game, you will encounter a room with a large machine in it.  Plug into it, and the teleport ability is unlocked.

[image: Image of the room in question]

To teleport you click on your desired location. This requires at least one energy block in the current room to have been activated. Be aware that when you teleport all blocks in the adjacent squares to your starting position will be deactivated - including energy blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have it from the start.

You need some energy (have to find atleast one energy block) to be able to teleport.

Comment: As in, per room?  I was trying this in a room that had a full energy meter, but still nothing seemed to be happening...